# How to run a function from content script, when an injected button was clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am injecting a button through the content script of my chrome extension like this:

```
btnHtml += '<button id="btn1" style="background-color: #2c3f82; height: 25px; width: 50px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 4px; color: white; border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); font-size: 15px; margin: 2px;">someText</button>'
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'ownSizes';
div.innerHTML = '<div style="display: inline-grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto; background-color: #1d76ce; border-radius: 8px; padding: 10px;">'+btnHtml+'</div>';
document.getElementsByClassName('_4NtqZU')[0].appendChild(div);
```

That works fine. Now how can I add a function to the button? Do I have to inject a new js into the page or is there an easier way?

Comment: Just use `document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', yourFunction...)` after the code you posted.

Comment: already tried that, but the function will not run when the button was clicked but instead the function just starts once when the script gets to the point where I added the event listener

Comment: Make sure you do something like `addEventListener('click', myFunction)` and not `addEventListener('click', myFunction() )`. Do not invoke the function when adding the listener.

Comment: Oh seems like there was my mistake, thanks a lot! Is there some way to pass an argument to the function?

Comment: .problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are having is due to not being able to reach your scope because you're adding the element by injecting strings of html.

Alternatively, you could create the button by using the [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) function to give you an actual node that you can inject into the page.

```
let btn = document.createElement('button' [, options]);
```

Then you can bind you click event from the current scope

```
btn.onclick = //some function
```

Lastly inject into the page using appendChild as you have in your question.

Comment: this sadly doesnt work too. With this method I get the same problem as when I use an event listener,  the function will not run when the button was clicked, but instead the function just starts once when the script gets to the point where I added the event listener/onclick

Comment: That typically happens when you do something like .onclick = doSomething()
If you remove the parenthesis from the function name it will work.